# Balanced Symbol Check using Stack in Java

Tags: java, string, stack

Hey guys so I have an assignment where Im supposed to read a string that the user inputs and check for balanced symbols using a stack. So if the string is "{[()]}" the string is balanced because there is a close for every opening. My thought is to use a loop that checks every character from the string that is given and if the string has an opener such as "([{" then it does stack.push(char) and if the character is a closer ")]}" then I need to use stack.pop(char). The issue im running into is that my professor is forcing me to use a string method and any help ive found online is using a boolean method, id appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

I understand that my code is not working but you can at least get the idea of what my logic is.

import java.util.*;

public class BalancedSymbols {

```
public static String balancedSymbols(String lineToCheck){ //this is the method that im being forced to use

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

   for (int i = 0; i<lineToCheck.length(); i++){

        char x = '(';
        char y = '{';
        char z = '[';

        char a;
        a = lineToCheck.charAt(i);

        if (a == x){

            stack.push(a);

        }

        if (a == y){

            stack.push(a);

        }

        if (a == z){

            stack.push(a);

        }


    }

}
```

}

Obviously I would do the same for popping except with different symbols.

Comment: I assume you are being "forced" to use that because of some requirements you aren't telling us about. What did your professor say that method needed to return?

Comment: We just need to return whether the string is balanced or not. If its balanced then we say that the string is balanced and if its not balanced then we have to tell what symbol doesnt match and at what position it doesn't match.

Comment: Possibly same as the link below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930073/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-balanced

Comment: @UsmanHasan So do that; it's mildly inconvenient that you're required to return a string but it doesn't add the difficulty you think it does. Determine the info you need (balanced vs. not, and unbalanced position), *then* construct the string to return at the very last minute. E.g. imagine a comment near the end that says "at this point, `isBalanced` is a boolean indicating whether or not its balanced, and if it's not, the int `unbalancedPosition` contains the position" with a big line above it -- then stick those in a string and return that. Divide and conquer, as it were.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic:

Create empty stack. (you already have done it).

Traverse through the String.

For every character `ch` you encounter, if ch is **} ] )** and stack is empty **return false** 
 else

if it is **( { [** *push* it in **stack**
if `ch`
is **) } ]** *check* **stack top**.

if stack top is equal  to corresponding opening bracket pop from stack else **return false**. 
If you have reached to end of String and stack is not empty **return false** 
**else return true**. 
 The reason behind returning false is we don't have corresponding matching parenthesis for this. *These are extra brackets*.

Try to implement it on your own first. If you face any problem, comment it.. I'll be happy to help.

Please comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Create empty stack
 ==========================

private static boolean isValideEx(String str) {

    Stack<Character> st=new Stack<Character>();

    if(str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)==')'){
                if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek()=='('){
                    st.pop();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }else if(str.charAt(i)==']'){
                if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek()=='['){
                    st.pop();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='}'){
                if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek()=='{'){
                    st.pop();
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }else{
            st.push(str.charAt(i));
        }

    }
    System.out.println(" sy "+st);

    if(st.isEmpty())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```