# Determine if a string that contains parentheses is balanced

Tags: java, string, recursion

This is an school assignment ive been trying to solve for a week, i still havent gotten close to the real answer. If someone is so kind and guides me with some solid pointers it would be really apreciated, Notice i do not want the solution. 
For example, the strings () , [()] , {([])} ,  ()[]  are 4 balanced strings.

Write the Recursive method:`

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String in)
```

that returns true if in is a  balanced parentheses string and
false if it is not.

Here is some of the code ive been working on:

```
    public static boolean isBalanced(String in){
        if(in.length() == 0){
            return true;
        }
        char aux = in.charAt(0);
        if(aux == '{' ||aux == '[' ||aux == '(' ){
            if(aux == '{'){
                return isBalanced(in.substring(1));
            }
            if(aux == '}'){
                return false || isBalanced(in.substring(1));
            }
            if(aux == '['){
                return isBalanced(in.substring(1));
            }
            if(aux == ']'){
                return false || isBalanced(in.substring(1));
            }if(aux == '('){
                return isBalanced(in.substring(1));
            }
            if(aux == ')'){
                return false || isBalanced(in.substring(1));
            }
        }
        return isBalanced(in.substring(1));
    }   

}
```

Comment: The solution using stacks is really natural and easy to come up with, however i cant think recursively. Its like trying to writte with my oposite hand or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930073/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-balanced

Comment: @CarlosSanchez a stack is precisely used to avoid recursion. Using a stack, you just need a loop.

Comment: The thing is that all the answers here do not help me at all, i already have the bare idea of how to solve it using stacks, i need to solve it using recursion, and the signature can not change, moreover i cannot use any helper method cuz the method is static.

Comment: If you must solve it using recursion, please edit your question to mention it. We can't guess if you don't tell. I don't see why you couldn't use a helper method. Being a static method doesn't prevent it to call other methods.

Comment: Iam trying to call methods from the same class and it does not let me.

Comment: @JBNizet i cant call class methods within that static one for some reason.

Comment: The reason is explained in the error message you get. Read it, google it, and if you're stuck, post the code and the complete error message.

Comment: It doesnt even autocomplete the name of the method when trying to call it from within. I cant start deweling into the why of that now, ive seen the recursive solution for this implemented in c++, its just that it has a different signature, they used int isBalanced(String in){} instead. i cant use that due to the restrictions of my assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want a copy&paste solution, you should check out this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854415/1057547

it is written in PHP, but exlains the idea behind, which you can adapt easily.
The page to "validate" your input is still available: http://dog-net.org/string.php, so you can test "huge" strings without doing paperwork.

---

As of your comments, you require to implement an recursive approach. So, with the **given signature** of `isbalanced(String str)` There are two options in my mind to generate a recursive approach:

First, you could - in the first recursion call - iterate over the string using the described ways, **until** you are balanced **but** have a remaining string. Then you just need to recursivly call the method on the remaining string.

So, for the input String `() [()]{([])}()[]` the callstack should become:

```
isBalanced("()[()]{([])}()[]");
 isBalanced("[()]{([])}()[]");
  isBalanced("{([])}()[]");
   isBalanced("()[]");
     isBalanced("[]");
```

This however will **not** go into recursion for strings like `{([])}` - because they could be handled within one call.

The second way would be to enter recursion depending on "characters". So, you always seek for the matching bracket *of the first opening bracket* within ONE recursion call, replace **both** and continue with another call. This would be a slower solution - performance-wise - but allows recursion with the given signature.

The callstack then should look like:

```
isBalanced("()[()]{([])}()[]");
 isBalanced("__[()]{([])}()[]");
  isBalanced("___()_{([])}()[]");
   isBalanced("______{([])}()[]");
    isBalanced("_______([])_()[]");
     isBalanced("________[]__()[]");
      isBalanced("____________()[]");
       isBalanced("______________[]");
        isBalanced("________________");
```

ps.:
No matter what you do, don't forget to add

```
isBalanced(String str){
   if (str.length() % 2 != 0) return false;
   ...
}
```

for the "A+" :-)

Comment: hahah yeah i thought of the your A+ sugestion lol yeah its nice.

Comment: in the end i decided to go with two nested for loops to find each matching brackets, if there are no matches found return false else return the method with a substring. I dont know if that is cathegorized as recursion but hey it has a recursive call in it lol