# Boolean Method which returns true if brackets match

Tags: java, regex, string, char

I am trying to write a method that takes a string of curly brackets and returns true if the brackets match up and false if they don’t.

These are examples of brackets matching:

{ }

{ } { }

{ { } }

{ { { } { { } } } }

These are examples of the brackets not matching:

{

} {

{ { }

{ { } } } { }

I am not able to figure out the proper logic behind this code. I first tried length() mod 2, and only if the result was 0, the method would return true. But obviously, there was a bug because it would return true even for strings such as } {. I added some more code which detects {, and if it doesn't find }, it automatically returns false. But I am still receiving errors.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean bracketsMatch(String brackets)
{
    if(!(brackets.length() % 2 == 0))
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        boolean check = false;
        while(brackets.charAt(i) == '{')
        {
            for(int o = i + 1; o < brackets.length(); o++)
            {
                if(o == '}')
                {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                j++;
                }
            }

            if(check == false)
                return false;

            i + = j;
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What would be the correct logic for this problem, and what mistakes am I making? Thanks!

Comment: Try looking on [`CodeGolf`](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). I've seen such a logic displayed in one post.

Comment: Or nearly any tutorial on stacks which use this as the test case.

Comment: What you are looking for, is called "Balanced parentheses" and can be wildly found here on SO, e.g. at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930073/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-balanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use counter. Increase it when you find `{` and decrease when find `}`. If at some point counter is negative, string is not valid. Return true if after handling all characters counter is `0`.

OK

```
{ }
1 0

{ } { }
1 0 1 0

{ { } }
1 2 1 0

{ { { } { { } } } }
1 2 3 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
```

Not OK

```
{
1

}  {
-1   <- no point checking farther

{ { }
1 2 1 

{ { } }  } { }
1 2 1 0 -1  <- no point checking farther
```

Comment: @BigBoss Why is odd relevant? Surely finishing at zero is the only positive case.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through the string, if you get an open bracket push it to a stack, if you get a close bracket pop an open bracket from the stack. If the stack is empty when popping, or if when you're finished iterating there are open brackets still on the stack then your brackets are not balanced

If you are checking for the balanced-ness of multiple types ie () [] {} etc then when you pop you need to make sure that the popped opening bracket is of the same type as the closing bracket you have just encountered, if not the brackets are not balanced.

Comment: This is how we did it in school. I find stacks to be the best for this kind of problem. Ex: for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){ if (str.charAt(i) == '{') { stack.push(str.charAt(i)) } else if ( stack.peek() == '{' && str.charAt(i) == '}' ) { stack.pop(); } } return (stack.size() == 0); ~~ sorry for mobile formatting

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't learned what stacks are yet. That is what my next project will hopefully be.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the algorithm described in [@Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095641/2970947) and an elegant implementation occured to me; you could increment the `count` on `{` decrement on `}` and `return false` if the result is negative with a simpler `for-each` loop and a `switch`. Remembering, to check that the `count` is `0` at the end with something like

```
public static boolean bracketsMatch(String brackets) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : brackets.toCharArray()) {
        switch (ch) {
        case '{': count++; break;
        case '}': if (--count < 0) return false;
        }
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```

I also created a small unit test for the above using your scenarios

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] good = { "{ }", "{ } { }", "{ { } }", "{ { { } { { } } } }" };
    String[] bad = { "{", "} {", "{ { }", "{ { } } } { }" };
    for (String str : good) {
        if (!bracketsMatch(str)) {
            System.out.printf("error with good: %s%n", str);
        }
    }
    for (String str : bad) {
        if (bracketsMatch(str)) {
            System.out.printf("error with bad: %s%n", str);
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation here passes.